# using sed to copy lines and delete characters from the duplicates

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
@"Afghanistan.png",
@"Albania.png",
@"Algeria.png",
@"American_Samoa.png",
```

I want it to look like this

```
@"Afghanistan.png",
@"Afghanistan",
@"Albania.png",
@"Albania",
@"Algeria.png",
@"Algeria",
@"American_Samoa.png",
@"American_Samoa",
```

I thought I could use sed to do this but I can't figure out how to store something in a buffer and then modify it.

Am I even using the right tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is pretty easy to do with sed and you not even need to use the hold space (the sed auxiliary buffer). Given the `input` file below:

```
$ cat input 
@"Afghanistan.png",
@"Albania.png",
@"Algeria.png",
@"American_Samoa.png",
```

you should use this command:

```
sed 's/@"\([^.]*\)\.png",/&\
@"\1",/' input
```

The result:

```
$ sed 's/@"\([^.]*\)\.png",/&\
@"\1",/' input 
@"Afghanistan.png",
@"Afghanistan",
@"Albania.png",
@"Albania",
@"Algeria.png",
@"Algeria",
@"American_Samoa.png",
@"American_Samoa",
```

This commands is just a replacement command (`s///`). It matches anything starting with `@"` followed by non-period chars (`[^.]*`) and then by `.png",`. Also, it matches all non-period chars before `.png",` using the group brackets `\(`  and `\)`, so we can get what was matched by this group. So, this is the to-be-replaced regular expression:

```
@"\([^.]*\)\.png",
```

So follows the replacement part of the command. The `&` command just inserts everything that was matched by `@"\([^.]*\)\.png",` in the changed content. If it was the only element of the replacement part, nothing would be changed in the output. However, following the `&` there is a newline character - represented by the backslash `\` followed by an actual newline - and in the new line we add the `@"` string followed by the content of the first group (`\1`) and then the string `",`.

This is just a brief explanation of the command. Hope this helps. Also, note that you can use the `\n` string to represent newlines in some versions of sed (such as GNU sed). It would render a more concise and readable command:

```
sed 's/@"\([^.]*\)\.png",/&\n@"\1",/' input
```

Comment: Outstanding. You wouldn't car to explain your command line fu would you?

Comment: I was just trying to explain it even before to read your comment :) Hope it makes the solution clearer. It would be a pleasure to answer any remaining question about it too.

Comment: In Bash the newline without \n is achieved by [Ctrl-V, Ctrl-J](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80820/72988)

Answer (score 19):

You don't have to get tricky with regular expressions and replacement strings: use sed's `p` command to print the line intact, then modify the line and let it print implicitly

```
sed 'p; s/\.png//'
```

Answer (score 18):

Glenn jackman's response is OK, but it also doubles the rows which do not match the expression.

This one, instead, doubles only the rows which matched the expression:

```
sed -n 'p; s/\.png//p'
```

Here, -n stands for "print nothing unless explicitely printed", and the p in `s/\.png//p` forces the print if substitution was done, but does not force it otherwise

Comment: For a code generator template I needed to duplicate only matching lines in target source file; this answer nailed it -- thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I prefer this over Carles Sala and Glenn Jackman's:

```
sed '/.png/p;s/.png//'
```

Could just say it's personal preference.

Comment: Shouldn't the `.` characters be escaped?  (Also, I'd recommend a space after the semicolon for readability.)

Answer (score 0):

or one can combine both versions and apply the duplication only on lines matching the required pattern

```
sed -e '/^@".*\.png",/{p;s/\.png//;}' input
```